# Different URLs pointing to same page okay for SEO?

Tags: seo, url

I am using a CMS which shows two links for the same page.

Example:

```
example.com/personal
example.com/personal/index.html
example.com/personal/index.html?abc=1
```

Is this ok? Or do search engines penalize me for this?

Comment: Very similar question but not quite duplicate: [Different urls to same page and redirect](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16783/different-urls-to-same-page-and-redirect).   I've been searching for an exact duplicate question and can't believe we don't already have this answered somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a good practice. For Google, these are 3 different URLs and they all have the same content. I would suggest using Canonical URL to avoid the Duplicate content issue.

Here is the official documentation by Google about the Duplicate content.
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en

Also, read Moz's Guide about avoiding description. 
https://moz.com/blog/duplicate-content-in-a-post-panda-world

Comment: These are not duplicate pages, its only the link.

Comment: @hunzaboy: Does this mean visitors end up on the same URL, no matter which of the three URLs they visit (i.e., they get redirected)? If not, that’s exactly the definition of a duplicate page, no?

Comment: @unor, gotcha. So canonical is the solution then.

Comment: @unor What if i add htaccess redirection instead of canonicals? Is that the same? Because i am using a CMS and adding canonicals is a bit complex and i have alot of pages with the same issue

Comment: @hunzaboy: A 301 redirect (e.g., with `.htaccess`) is preferable to `canonical` ([see why](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/90125/17633)).